# Can Cordova read/write files in the iOS "Files" app?

Tags: cordova

Does anyone know if the iOS "Files" application data can be accessed via Cordova? I.e., I want to add my application to the list of "Locations" in the Files application, and then read/write those files. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen any existing plugin for working with Files app, so currently the only way is to write your plugin which will work with Files app from objectiveC/swift and then use that plugin. Here are links about integration with Files app https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/managing-files-in-ios-dfcdfdc1f426 and https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/

Comment: I'm not sure if you need a plugin for this at all, is it not more a matter of writing files to the correct location with the file plugin? In the case of iOS  ~/Documents/ - per https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: No, I tried that. Nothing appears in the Files app. I specifically write to Documents/NoCloud/, but I assume it would be the same, if so.

Comment: @user2943799, any luck with this? I’m trying to accomplish the same thing...

Comment: @Joncom, No, unfortunately not. As far as I know, there is no plugin which provides this access.

Comment: @user2943799 That's unfortunate :(

Comment: I had a similar question. My solution was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825500/ionic-4-ios-file-access-with-ionic-native-file-ngx-cordova-plugin-file/59830631#59830631

Answer (score 1):

You must set iCloud under Capabilities in Xcode. Don't forget to set the Container for your App Identifier.

Maybe this option will help you in future:

[LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lssupportsopeningdocumentsinplace)

Comment: this and the `UIFileSharingEnabled` from @Bochi is what was needed.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue and resolved it. Here's what I did:
To give the files app access to my app's data, I had to open the info.plist file (just search for "info.plist" in your iOS platform folder) and add the following snippet:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Now, when you click on your Ressources > info.plist file in xcode, you should have this entry:

[Screenshot Data Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytdgu.png)

After building your app to your device, the files app should then give you access to "On My (Device)" and list all folders and files you created using the cordova file plugin.

Comment: I have a .txt file I downloaded to an iPhone. I can find the .txt file using the iPhone's Files icon under "On My iPhone". I have an ionic application using cordova-plugin-file. I try to read in the .txt using the plugins readAsText(). The key you mention - UIFileSharingEnabled - when I add to Xcode shows Application supports iTune file sharing not Supports opening documents in place which your screen shot shows? I added both to my Xcode project but am still not able to access the .txt file at "On My iPhone". What plugin are you using and how are you using it?

Comment: I used cordova without ionic in xcode 10.1. After adding the snippet, the "on my ipad" location got added to my "files" app. I then used cordova.plugin.file to create directories in cordova.file.documentsDirectory. From there it took me some time to parse array data to strings correctly, but eventually it worked. With predefined dummy strings, you shouldn't have that trouble, though.

Comment: this and the `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` from @hydrococcus is what was needed